Google Apps Script longer run time
I have a few programs on a Google Sheets through Google Apps Script. It was running smoothly for 6 month but since last wednesday, all my programs on Google Apps Script take way longer to run and hit the time limit from Google. For example a program that was taking 1min is now taking more than the 6min limit.
I didn't change those programs at all (I added a new function but it's not connected to the programs that take longer all of a sudden) and the longer run time is not specific to my computer or internet connection (I tried it with another computer, wifi and browser).
I have no idea why it suddenly takes longer, do you have any suggestion? Are Google servers having a problem? Do some of you have encounter such a problem before?
Thank you for your help!
Edit : Here is my code if it helps, the first program is one (of all the program whose run time changed) that used to run in less than a minute and now takes way more than the 6min run time limit and the second one is the one I just wrote and that is the only change in my file since the problem started occuring. I don't see how those two program interact except for writing one the same sheet... Since I'm french the comments are in french but that shouldn't stop you from being able to read the actual code.

function importSumUp() {
  Logger.log("Starting importSumUp function.");

  var fileUrl = 'www.myspecificgooglesheets.com';
  var fileId = fileUrl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  if (!fileId) {
    Logger.log("Invalid URL.");
    return;
  }
  fileId = fileId[0];
  Logger.log("File ID extracted: " + fileId);

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();

  var destinationSheetName = "Factures Vente";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);

  if (!destinationSheet) {
    Logger.log("Destination sheet not found.");
    return;
  }
  Logger.log("Destination sheet opened: " + destinationSheetName);

  // Récupérer les clés existantes dans la colonne B de la feuille de destination
  var destinationData = destinationSheet.getRange(2, 2, destinationSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  var existingKeys = destinationData.flat().filter(String); // Supprimer les cellules vides
  
  Logger.log("Existing keys in destination: " + existingKeys.join(", "));

  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    Logger.log("Processing sheet: " + sheetName);

    var sourceData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 12).getValues(); // Ajuster pour 12 colonnes
    var newRows = [];

    sourceData.forEach(function(sourceRow) {
      var key = sourceRow[0]; // Numéro de facture (Colonne A source)
      var conditionValue1 = sourceRow[9]; // Colonne J source
      var conditionValue2 = sourceRow[11]; // Colonne L source

      // Vérifier si les colonnes B à H sont toutes vides
      var allEmpty = sourceRow.slice(1, 8).every(function(cell) {
        return cell === '';
      });

      // Ajouter uniquement si la ligne respecte les conditions et si la clé n'existe pas
      if (!allEmpty && !existingKeys.includes(key) && conditionValue1 === "CA" && conditionValue2 === "SUMUP") {
        var newRow = [];

        // Remplissage des colonnes de destination selon le mappage requis
        newRow[0] = sourceRow[2]; // Date de facture (Colonne A destination, Colonne C source)
        newRow[1] = key; // Numéro de facture (Colonne B destination, Colonne A source)
        newRow[2] = (sourceRow[6] !== '' && !isNaN(sourceRow[6])) ? (sourceRow[6] /0.9825 / 1.2).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') : ''; // Montant HT
        newRow[3] = (sourceRow[6] !== '' && !isNaN(sourceRow[6])) ? ((sourceRow[6] /0.9825 / 1.2) * 0.2).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') : ''; // TVA
        newRow[4] = (sourceRow[6] !== '' && !isNaN(sourceRow[6])) ? (sourceRow[6] / 0.9825).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') : ''; // Montant TTC
        newRow[5] = (sourceRow[6] !== '' && !isNaN(sourceRow[6])) ? ((sourceRow[6] / 0.9825) * 0.0175).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') : ''; // Frais SumUp
        newRow[6] = "SumUp"; // Type de tiers (Colonne G destination)
        newRow[7] = "SumUp"; // Tiers (Colonne H destination)
        newRow[8] = ""; // Colonne I vide
        newRow[9] = sourceRow[2]; // Date de paiement (Colonne J destination, Colonne C source)
        newRow[10] = "SumUp"; // Mode de paiement (Colonne K destination)
        newRow[11] = "CE"; // Banque (Colonne L destination)

        newRows.push(newRow);
        existingKeys.push(key); // Ajouter à la liste pour éviter les doublons dans cette session
      }
    });

    if (newRows.length > 0) {
      destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newRows.length, newRows[0].length).setValues(newRows);
      Logger.log("Data from sheet '" + sheetName + "' copied successfully.");
    } else {
      Logger.log("No new data to copy from sheet '" + sheetName + "'.");
    }
  });

  Logger.log("importSumUp function completed.");
}



function copyRefundInvoicesSansFiltreDoublon() { 
  const sourceUrl = "www.myspecificgooglesheets.com";
  Logger.log("Ouverture du fichier source : %s", sourceUrl);

  const sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourceUrl);
  const destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Factures Vente");
  Logger.log("Fichier source ouvert et fichier de destination initialisé.");

  // Vérification de la feuille de destination
  if (!destinationSheet) {
    Logger.log("Erreur : La feuille 'Factures Vente' est introuvable.");
    throw new Error("La feuille 'Factures Vente' est introuvable.");
  }

  const sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  const keywords = ["Rbts", "Rbt", "Remboursements", "Remboursement"];
  let destinationData = [];
  let totalProcessed = 0; // Compteur global des lignes traitées

  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    if (keywords.some(keyword => sheetName.includes(keyword))) {
      Logger.log("Traitement de la feuille : %s", sheetName);
      const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

      // Récupération de la valeur de la cellule L2 de la feuille source
      const valueFromL2 = sheet.getRange("L2").getValue();
      let rowsProcessedInSheet = 0; // Compteur des lignes traitées dans cette feuille

      for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        const row = data[i];

        if (row[0] && typeof row[0] === 'string' && row[0].includes("#") && row[8]) {
          const refundNumber = "Rbt" + row[0];
          const refundHT = (row[4] || 0) + (row[5] || 0);
          const refundTVA = row[7] || 0;
          const refundTTC = row[8] || 0;
          const deliveryFees = row[5] || 0;
          const bank = "CE";
          const invoiceKey = row[0];

          const destinationDataRange = destinationSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
          let foundRow = null;

          // Vérification de la présence de la facture dans la feuille de destination
          for (let j = 0; j < destinationDataRange.length; j++) {
            if (destinationDataRange[j][1] === invoiceKey) {
              foundRow = destinationDataRange[j];
              break;
            }
          }

          if (foundRow) {
            const invoiceDate = foundRow[0];
            const typeTiers = foundRow[6];
            const tiers = foundRow[7];
            const paysLivraison = foundRow[8];
            const datePaiement = foundRow[9];
            const modePaiement = foundRow[10];

            // Ajouter les données de la facture
            destinationData.push([
              valueFromL2, // Colonne A - valeur de L2 de la feuille source
              refundNumber, // Colonne B
              refundHT, // Colonne C
              refundTVA, // Colonne D
              refundTTC, // Colonne E
              deliveryFees, // Colonne F
              typeTiers, // Colonne G
              tiers, // Colonne H
              paysLivraison, // Colonne I
              datePaiement, // Colonne J
              modePaiement, // Colonne K
              bank, // Colonne L
              row[14] // Nom de la feuille - Colonne O (index 14)
            ]);
          } else {
            // Si la facture n'est pas trouvée, ajouter une ligne avec des valeurs par défaut
            destinationData.push([
              valueFromL2, // Colonne A - valeur de L2 de la feuille source
              refundNumber, // Colonne B
              refundHT, // Colonne C
              refundTVA, // Colonne D
              refundTTC, // Colonne E
              deliveryFees, // Colonne F
              "", "", "", "", "", // Colonnes G à K vides
              bank, // Colonne L
              row[14] // Nom de la feuille - Colonne O (index 14)
            ]);
          }

          rowsProcessedInSheet++;
        }
      }

      if (rowsProcessedInSheet > 0) {
        totalProcessed += rowsProcessedInSheet;
        Logger.log("Feuille '%s' traitée : %d lignes ajoutées.", sheetName, rowsProcessedInSheet);
      }
    }
  });

  // Écrire les données dans la feuille de destination
  if (destinationData.length > 0) {
    const lastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
    Logger.log("Ajout de %d lignes à partir de la ligne %d dans la feuille de destination.", destinationData.length, lastRow + 1);
    
    // Ajuster la plage cible pour correspondre au nombre de colonnes de destinationData
    const numCols = destinationData[0].length; // Nombre dynamique de colonnes
    destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, destinationData.length, numCols).setValues(destinationData); 
    Logger.log("%d lignes copiées dans la feuille de destination. Nombre total de lignes traitées : %d.", destinationData.length, totalProcessed);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Aucune donnée à copier.");
  }
}


Kindly share a minimal, reproducible example—no sensitive data with your desired output—that the community can use to replicate and see what you'd like to do.

You may use Tables or tools like Table to Markdown that can easily be copied and pasted. If necessary, as a last resort, Make an anonymous sample document.

FWIW (and as you probably already know), the logger.log statements slow down execution substantially.

@Tedinoz thank you for your feedback I tried it without the logger.log and it was a bit quicker but still not what it used to be. And I don't get why the run time changed when both the code and the datasource didn't change. And to add to it, today some program run smoothly again and some other take too long and meet the run time limit. I don't get the apparent randomness of it all to be honest...

Videorama17, the type of problem that you are experiencing is largely beyond our control; there are many factors that impact on execution time. However IF you want an independent assessment of execution time, then you should provide an MRE as requested by @Saddles in the very first comment.
